# i tried to declare and initialsie a auxillary string but got these errors

Tags: java, string, function, initialization, declaration

```
String b="";
b.length()=n;
        ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
revstring.java:22: error: unexpected type
b.charAt(i)=str.charAt(n-i-1);
        ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
2 errors
```

Comment: You can't assign a value to a method.

Comment: that was not a method sir-i wanted to create an auxillary string initialissing it with null

Comment: `b.length()` and `b.charAt(i)` do not return variables, they return values. You can't assign to a value. It would be like trying to do `1 = 12;`.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, when you use an `=` you are assigning a *variable* on the left side to the *value* on the right side. In your issue, you have the line `b.length() = n;`. Here you are telling java to assign the *method* `b.length()` to the *value* of `n`, which doesn't make sense to java (not to mention that `n` doesn't exist).

I'm not really sure what an auxiliary string is, but if you are trying to store the value of `b.length()` into a variable `n`. To do that you need to write `int n = b.length();`.

If you are having problems at this level, I suggest you take a basic course on java. Sites like [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/catalog/language/java) have pretty good free ones. Good luck!

Comment: "you are assigning a variable on the left side to the value on the right side" the opposite, actually :)

Comment: And "Here you are telling java to assign the method `b.length()` to the value of `n`" no, that's not what's happening. See my comment to the question.

Comment: Sorry, bad wording. I should've said, "In Java, when you use an `=` you **should** be..."

Comment: I guess you are right. Java evaluates `b.length()` to a value before it attempts to assign it...but that's not really the point. I'm trying to say that the asker has the order backwards for assigning a variable (and that they're missing a type).

Comment: thanks for the help.I have just started learning java.I m having difficulty in creating a temporary string in java -to be used in one of the  methods .how do i do that,could someone assist?

Comment: I don't know what a temporary string is in java. I think you may be confused about something here. If you show me what you are trying to accomplish, I might be able to help; however, I still think you would be better off if you simply took a java course online.